# How to detect CSS translate3d without the webkit context?

Tags: css, translate3d

To detect if a browser support `translate3d` we can use (`WebKitCSSMatrix` in window && `m11` in new WebKitCSSMatrix())

but now that firefox support `translate3d` how to have a correct detection of it?

The idea would be to find a solution without using Modernizr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed something similar. I wanted to test if a browser supported translate3d without using a library. I didn't find any good generic test that wasn't webkit specific. So after much experimentation, I came up with the following test. I first create a test element, assign a transform function to it, then see if the element retained the transform function.

```
function Has3DSupport()
{
    var sTranslate3D = "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)";

    var eTemp = document.createElement("div");

    eTemp.style.cssText = "  -moz-transform:"    + sTranslate3D +
                          "; -ms-transform:"     + sTranslate3D +
                          "; -o-transform:"      + sTranslate3D +
                          "; -webkit-transform:" + sTranslate3D +
                          "; transform:"         + sTranslate3D;
    var rxTranslate = /translate3d\(0px, 0px, 0px\)/g;
    var asSupport = eTemp.style.cssText.match(rxTranslate);
    var bHasSupport = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length == 1);

    return bHasSupport;
} // Has3DSupport
```

The function is plenty fast for my needs: < 50 microseconds in desktop browsers, < 500 microseconds in mobile browsers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option who works like a charm for me:

```
function has3d() {
    var el = document.createElement('p'), 
        has3d,
        transforms = {
            'WebkitTransform':'-webkit-transform',
            'OTransform':'-o-transform',
            'MSTransform':'-ms-transform',
            'MozTransform':'-moz-transform',
            'Transform':'transform'
        };

    // Add it to the body to get the computed style.
    document.body.insertBefore(el, null);

    for (var t in transforms) {
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
            el.style[t] = "translate3d(1px,1px,1px)";
            has3d = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(transforms[t]);
        }
    }

    document.body.removeChild(el);

    return (has3d !== undefined && has3d.length > 0 && has3d !== "none");
}
```